# What is "It turns out that..." in standard German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, standard-german

How do you say *It turns out that...* in German?

> Der Mann von gegenüber stellt sich heraus, dass er ein guter Kerl ist.

Are there other ways to say it?

Comment: In English you start the sentence with "It turned out that...". In German you usually do the same: "Es stellte sich heraus, dass..." Siehe auch [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/It+turned+out+that.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man kann sowohl Satzbau als auch Formulierung variieren. Sich herausstellen, zeigen, erweisen sind mögliche Formulierungen. In unterschiedlichem Satzbau hier:

```
Der Mann von gegenüber stellt sich als (ein) guter Kerl heraus.    
Es stellt sich heraus, dass der Mann von gegenüber ein guter Kerl ist. 
Es zeigt sich, dass der Mann von gegenüber ein guter Kerl ist.     
Der Mann von gegenüber erweist sich als guter Kerl.
```

Answer (score 5):

'**It turns out**' is translated '**es stellt sich heraus**'.

There are different sentence constructions with this expression that you need to keep apart:

A) In two clauses:

> **Es stellt sich heraus, dass** der Mann ein guter Kerl ist.
>   **It turns out (that)** the man is a good guy.

and a variation of this:

> **Wie sich herausstellt,** ist der Mann ein guter Kerl.
>   **As it turns out,** the man is a good guy.

B) In a single clause:

> Der Mann **stellt sich als** guter Kerl **heraus**.
>   The man **turns out to be** a good guy.

You'll also find the expression 'sich erweisen als':

> Der Mann **hat sich als** guter Kerl **erwiesen**.
>   The man **has proved to be** a good guy.

In a another sentence construction:

> Der Mann, **so stellt sich heraus**, ist ein guter Kerl.
>   The man, **it (so) turns out**, is a good guy.

Comment: Es ginge auch: "Der Mann von gegenüber, es stellt sich heraus, dass er ein guter Kerl ist".